# Get current used stack size for win7

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, stack

is there a windows7 function for GetCurrentThreadStackLimits which seems to work only on windows >= 8 ? [1] and - if not - how can i achieve this info on win 7?

I need to find the current threads used stack size. (usedstacksize != maximumstacksize)

Thank you!

PS: It is for diagnostic purpose. We need to find the stack size to reserve for a stm32 application and i just wanted to make the pc simulation working too.

[1]: When calling the function the program compiles but at runtime a messagebox pops up that says "function entry point can not be found in kernel32.dll" The documentation states windows8 is required for this function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthreadstacklimits

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear, for me at least. if you what to check the stack size of a process in win7 @RbMm answered it. if you want to write an emulator, why don't create a large stack (let's say 2MB or larger) and, create some sort of page guard to detect stack overflow, and if you do reach the stack limit either statically make it larger or do it dynamically (it will impact performance, but it's your choice of stack implementation).

Comment: In order to find the maximum stack size on stm32, you must calculate the maximum number of nested functions called by the stm32 application. you have to add the interrupted functions call (like timer \ watchdog) if exists to the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to find the current threads used stack size. (usedstacksize !=
>   maximumstacksize)

in this case the `GetCurrentThreadStackLimits` wrong function for you at all, because it return *allocated* stack size. so *maximumstacksize* possible stack size. but usual most memory is reserved, yet not allocated. if you want exactly used stack size - you need read it from `NT_TIB`

```
void GetCurrentThreadUsedStackLimits(PULONG_PTR LowLimit,  PULONG_PTR HighLimit )
{
    NT_TIB* tib = (NT_TIB*)NtCurrentTeb();
    *HighLimit = (ULONG_PTR)tib->StackBase;
    *LowLimit = (ULONG_PTR)tib->StackLimit;
}
```

the `HighLimit` will be the same which return `GetCurrentThreadStackLimits`, but `LowLimit` will be usual different - the `GetCurrentThreadStackLimits` return allocation base of stack (so it possible maximum size, when `NT_TIB.StackLimit` is currently allocated stack limit (which can grow down)

---

if you want implement functionality of `GetCurrentThreadStackLimits` (but note - it not return *maximum* stack size. you can do next:

```
ULONG GetCurrentThreadStackLimits_old( _Out_ PULONG_PTR LowLimit, _Out_ PULONG_PTR HighLimit )
{
    static void (WINAPI* GetCurrentThreadStackLimits)(PULONG_PTR , PULONG_PTR);

    if (!GetCurrentThreadStackLimits)
    {
        *(void**)&GetCurrentThreadStackLimits = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32"), "GetCurrentThreadStackLimits");

        if (!GetCurrentThreadStackLimits)
        {
            NT_TIB* tib = (NT_TIB*)NtCurrentTeb();
            *HighLimit = (ULONG_PTR)tib->StackBase;

            MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
            if (VirtualQuery(tib->StackLimit, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
            {
                *LowLimit = (ULONG_PTR)mbi.AllocationBase;
                return 0;
            }

            return GetLastError();
        }
    }

    GetCurrentThreadStackLimits(LowLimit, HighLimit);
    return 0;
}
```

so we first try get address of `GetCurrentThreadStackLimits` from `"kernel32"`. possible and use [`"api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/windows-8-api-sets) here instead `"kernel32"`. if we got system suplied function pointer - use it. if no (win7 -) - yourself query this limits

---

Comment: The code is supposed to run on the [STM32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32) architecture. This proposed answer doesn't acknowledge that.

Comment: @IInspectable - how this related to `stm32` ? and main what is wrong in my code ? concrete what is not correct ?

Comment: @IInspectable: The app is for stm, but i am talking about the pc simulation for the app which runs on win32....

Comment: @charly_b - how i understand you need windows generic code. and i paste it - which will be work on every windows and platform.

Comment: @cha: *"i just wanted to make the pc simulation working too"* - That doesn't read like you **only** want this to run on a PC.

Comment: @IInspectable - how the answer must acknowledge of stm32 ? what is wrong here ?

Answer (score -5):

i found a suprisingly easy 'quick and dirty' solution. (which is quite obvious)

It's just declaring a local variable in a function and getting the adress of that variable:

```
uint GetCurrentStackAdress()
{
  uint aDummy;
  return reinterpret_cast<uint>(&aDummy);
}
```

That should work on most systems i guess and for my diagnostic purpose its dirty enough ;-).

Comment: Why the downvotes, if this does what the OP wants?  If you want to downvote, downvote the _question_ for lack of clarity.  Also, this code will not work for 64 bit apps - return INT_PTR or similar.